# Why does File.dirname returns a period when I expect a path?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to get the directory of a file on a Windows box using `File.dirname`.  I get the file ("file1" below) from the Windows box and return it to my the Mac OS X box that the script is run on.

`file1 = "C:\Administrator\proj1\testFile.txt"` below is to simplify my example, however, to make it more clear, I am getting this value from a remote box and returning it to my development box:

```
file1 = "C:\Administrator\proj1\testFile.txt"
path = "#{File.dirname(file1)}"
puts "#{path}"

>> .
```

I am confused on why it would return `'.'`.  I saw on ruby-doc.org that `File.dirname` says the following:

> "Returns all components of the filename given in file_name except the last one. The filename can be formed using both File::SEPARATOR and File::ALT_SEPARETOR as the separator when File::ALT_SEPARATOR is not nil."

I did a `puts` on `File::SEPARATOR` and `File::ALT_SEPARATOR` and got the following:

```
File::SEPARATOR >> /
File::ALT_SEPARATOR >>
```

I assumed it was because "\" wasn't a valid file separator.  So I set `File::ALT_SEPARATOR` to "\".  However, even after that, I still got the same value when I `puts path`.

I tried using `File.realdirpath` and this was the result:

```
file1 = "C:\Administrator\proj1\testFile.txt"
path = "#{File.realdirpath(file1)}"
puts "{path}"

>>  /Users/me/myProject/C:\Administrator\proj1\testFile.txt
```

It seemed to add the path from where I called the Ruby script and appended the full path (including the file name).  Seems to be odd behavior.

Any ideas, comments or suggestions would be great.

Comment: There is something wrong in your code. `puts "path"` will print the string `path`, not even a dot.

Comment: Sorry.  Just copied it over wrong.  Fixed now.

Comment: why are you using string interpolation ?

Comment: use [`File::realdirpath`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/File.html#method-c-realdirpath), which will give you what you want.

Comment: Ok so File::realdirpath gave me back something strange.  It gave me my current path followed by the full path (including file) for what I put in.

I will edit my original post to show what it did.

Comment: A `.` is the UNIX path notation for the current directory. Is `C:\Administrator\proj1` the directory with your code in it?

Comment: Also, you don't need all of that string interpolation. It's meaningless in this case.

Comment: Sorry I may have left out just a bit of information.  I will add it to my OP.  But basically File1 is a file on a remote box (Windows).  We get the path and return it to the box that this script is run on (Mac OS X).  When i say 'file1 = "C:\Administrator\proj1\testFile.txt"  That is just what file1 is returned as (I already verified that part works).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  It was an issue with the version of Ruby I was using.  I was using ruby 1.9.3 and then I switched to jruby 1.7.3 and it works correctly now.

Comment: It shouldn't have anything to do with a Ruby version, as jRuby is supposed to exhibit the same behavior with path resolution that MRI does. In either case they should be relying on the underlying OS.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you declare `file1`, those backslashes define escape characters. Notice the return:

```
file1 = "C:\Administrator\proj1\testFile.txt"
=> "C:Administratorproj1\testFile.txt"
```

If you want to store a filepath in a string, you either need to use forward slashes or double backslashes (to escape the escape character):

```
file1 = "C:\\Administrator\\proj1\\testFile.txt"
file1 = "C:/Administrator/proj1/testFile.txt"
```

Comment: I don't actually set the string.  That is what I get back from the remote Windows box

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was able to duplicate this problem as well.

As @fbonetti pointed out, you have to enclose your directory with single quotes to keep ruby from interpreting the backslashes as escapes, so start with that...

```
>> file1='C:\Administrator\proj1\testFile.txt'
=> "C:\\Administrator\\proj1\\testFile.txt"
```

Then, passing file1 through gsub to 'normalize' the slashes, gives you the results you're expecting.

```
>> File.dirname(file1.gsub('\\', '/'))
=> "C:/Administrator/proj1"
```

Of course, you could always reverse the gsub if you needed them to be backslashes again.

```
>> File.dirname(file1.gsub('\\', '/')).gsub('/', '\\')
=> "C:\\Administrator\\proj1"
```

Comment: Better yet, instead of using backslashes at all, do what Ruby's IO documentation says to do, and use forward-slashes.

Comment: I assumed the backslashes were being fed via some other source.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby's IO documentation is of great help when dealing with different OS path separators. From [the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html):

> Ruby will convert pathnames between different operating system conventions if possible. For instance, on a Windows system the filename "/gumby/ruby/test.rb" will be opened as "\gumby\ruby\test.rb". When specifying a Windows-style filename in a Ruby string, remember to escape the backslashes:

```
"c:\\gumby\\ruby\\test.rb"
```

> Our examples here will use the Unix-style forward slashes; File::ALT_SEPARATOR can be used to get the platform-specific separator character.

So, in other words, you don't need to hassle with backslashes, and whether you need to use single or double-quotes. Keep it simple, and use forward-slashes and let Ruby worry about it. That way your code is portable across *nix/Mac OS and Windows.

Beyond that, it looks like there's a real need to learn how character escaping works in double-quoted strings vs. single-quoted strings. This is from "[Programming Ruby](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/language.html#UD)":

> Ruby provides a number of mechanisms for creating literal strings. Each generates objects of type String. The different mechanisms vary in terms of how a string is delimited and how much substitution is done on the literal's content.
>
> Single-quoted string literals (' stuff ' and %q/stuff/) undergo the least substitution. Both convert the sequence into a single backslash, and the form with single quotes converts \' into a single quote.

```
'hello' »   hello
'a backslash \'\\\''    »   a backslash '\'
%q/simple string/   »   simple string
%q(nesting (really) works)  »   nesting (really) works
%q no_blanks_here ; »   no_blanks_here
```

> Double-quoted strings ("stuff", %Q/stuff/, and %/stuff/) undergo additional substitutions, shown in Table 18.2 on page 203.
>
> Substitutions in double-quoted strings

```
\\a Bell/alert   (0x07) \\nnn     Octal nnn
\\b Backspace    (0x08) \\xnn     Hex nn
\\e Escape       (0x1b) \\cx      Control-x
\\f Formfeed     (0x0c) \\C-x     Control-x
\\n Newline      (0x0a) \\M-x     Meta-x
\\r Return       (0x0d) \\M-\\C-x Meta-control-x
\\s Space        (0x20) \\x       x
\\t Tab          (0x09) #{expr}   Value of  expr
\\v Vertical tab (0x0b)


a  = 123
"\123mile"  »   Smile
"Say \"Hello\"" »   Say "Hello"
%Q!"I said 'nuts'," I said! »   "I said 'nuts'," I said
%Q{Try #{a + 1}, not #{a - 1}}  »   Try 124, not 122
%<Try #{a + 1}, not #{a - 1}>   »   Try 124, not 122
"Try #{a + 1}, not #{a - 1}"    »   Try 124, not 122
```